# Angular2: How do you mark FormGroup control dirty via `patchValue()`

Tags: angular

I am updating a Reactive `FormGroup` control value from my component via [patchValue](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html#!#patchValue).

Ex:

```
this.myForm.patchValue({incidentDate:'2016-09-12');
```

This works great and triggers a `valueChanges` event, however this control's `dirty` property is still `false`.

I need the `incidentDate` control to be `dirty` so my validation logic knows to run against this control.

How do I update the value of a control from my component AND indicate that it is dirty?

Here is my validation logic:

```
onValueChanged(data?: any) {
    if (!this.myForm) {
      return;
    }
    const form = this.myForm;
    for (const field in this.formErrors) {
      // clear previous error message (if any)
      this.formErrors[field] = '';
      const control = form.get(field);
      if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
        const messages: any = this.validationMessages[field];
        for (const key in control.errors) {
          this.formErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I usually do this:

```
this.formControl.markAsDirty()
```

Or in your case it could be:

```
this.myForm.get('incidentDate').markAsDirty()
```

Comment: You my friend, are the man.  Curious, where did you find this documented? It is no where to be found in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html

Comment: I come here quite regularly https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/forms/src/model.ts lol

Comment: I like it when people take me straight into source code.

Comment: ... but the link is broken now.

Comment: @HarryNinh now you can make this 
        this.form.get('incidentDate').markAsDirty(); 
which I find nicer

Comment: I needed to add add a call to `this.formControl.updateValueAndValidity()` after the `markAsDirty()` to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

mark as dirty controls(only those with value) inside FormGroup

```
  markDirtyAllControlsWithValue(form: FormGroup): void {
    const recursiveFunc = (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
      Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {
        const control = formGroup.get(field);
        if (control.value !== null && control.value !== undefined && control.value !== '') {
          control.markAsDirty();
        }
        if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
          recursiveFunc(control);
        }
      });
    };
    recursiveFunc(form);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a group or array that you need to mark as dirty you can use this

```
export class Helpers {
/**
   * Loop and touch all it has
   *
   * @param {FormGroup} formGroup
   * @param func << function name: [markAsTouched, markAsUntouched, markAsDirty, markAsPristine, markAsPending
   * @param opts
   *
   */
  public static touchAll(formGroup: FormGroup|FormArray, func = 'markAsDirty', opts = {onlySelf: false}): void {
    mapValues(formGroup.controls, (c, i) => {
      if (c instanceof FormGroup || c instanceof FormArray)
        Helpers.touchAll(c, func, opts);
      else
        c[func](opts);
    })
  }
}
```

You can use the [SuperForm npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-super-validator) to do that for you.